# Image compression and thumbnail creation for PHP

Tags: php, image-processing

I need some PHP classes that deal with image processing in a good manner. I have made a thumbnail creator myself but the end result quality is just horrible.

Is it also possible to let PHP convert and save all images to one type. For example take an image(jpg,png,gif), compress it, resize it, and save as png.

Can anyone recommend some good classes for this.

Comment: "I need some classes" is not a programming question in my opinion. But google skills one.

Comment: I was just looking for some recommendations. There are a lot available on Google, that's whats making me a bit confused. I have used a few, but I am not happy with the results.

Comment: @Col: It is funny that you quote the first part of the question, and then totally ignore the second and third part. Which bot are programming related.

Comment: It might be useful to show us the code you've written so far, tell us why you're not happy with it, and we *may* be able to resolve that.

Comment: It is kind of a big class, so it would not be practical to paste this here. But thank you for the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at this one
http://shiftingpixel.com/2008/03/03/smart-image-resizer/

Comment: This is still not completely what I want. I don't see the option of converting the different file formats into one.

Comment: @Saif actually this script does far more than you even imagine to expect. But being too picky you just prove my point: noone can bring you what you want. So, good luck in search.

Answer (score 3):

Check out https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine, given you use PHP 5.3, it will solve most of your image processing needs

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the php [gd](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php) library, or [imageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/), which has bindings for php.

Comment: Should I write this from scratch? Are there no classes available online that have these functions build in already?

Comment: Oh yeah I have bot gd and imageMagick installed.

Comment: You can't even imagine how **many** classes available online, @Saif
Just google for PHP image resize. though its up to you - to write it from scratch or use ready made one

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to command-line i'd recommend [image magic](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). The comman-line version has the advantage that it includes several features for batch processing.

Comment: Sorry I want to do this in PHP